# Unit testing WCF-RIA Services

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, wcf-ria-services

When data from a Get operation on my `DomainService` is sent to the `DomainContext` in my silverlight application, some rows end up not being sent while others are sent. I check this by setting a breakpoint in the `DomainService` and a breakpoint in the `DomainContext` load operation callback. How can I create a unit test to check this?

E.g. Set up some in-memory data for the `DomainService` and check if the silverlight `DomainContext` receives this data?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by a primary key that isn't unique. When RIA Services sends rows to the client it filters the results by the primary key to make sure there are no duplicates. If you have two rows with different data but the same primary key only one of those rows will make it to the client.

There is a blog series by Kyle McClellan on how to unit test RIA Services: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2011/08/18/unit-testing-a-wcf-ria-domainservice-part-1-the-idomainservicefactory.aspx which may be helpful.